# Funds Performance system

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create a WordPress system where I can track how money is being spent on different projects and how projects are performing For Example If I have 3 projects, I want to know how much was allocated to each project and how has it been spent. (Spent on what).
My system will have Projects, Project Members, Member Roles, Amount Allocated, Amount Utilised, etc. So I need to be able to Track each Project. The Admin will have a wider/general view of the finances.

Does anyone have an idea on which plugins I can use to help with this.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You'll have to custom build either a single plugin or a series of smaller, modular plugins that work together to achieve what you want in a manner that works exactly the way you want.  This is a project management application.

Comment: Well Noted. Thank you